# How do I install a missing ROS package?

Tags: ros, rosdep, stack, rosinstall, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
How do I install packages that I can't use roscd to find?

I try to type something like `rosdep install pr2_2dnav_gazebo`,
and I got:

```
sam@sam-desktop:~/code/ros$ rosdep install pr2_2dnav_gazebo
executing this script:
 set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
sam@sam-desktop:~/code/ros$
```

Then I try to open another try to use roscd but failed again...
How I install any package I missed like pr2_2dnav_gazebo?
Or how I install all packages on ros.org?
thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9201/how-do-i-install-a-missing-ros-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS packages may have two kinds of dependencies: (1) system dependencies, and (2) other ROS packages. The `rosdep` command is for system dependencies.

When you need a ROS package that is not currently available on your system:

- See what stack contains the package you need:
- Stacks are the basic unit of release and installation in ROS. Installing individual packages often works, but I do not recommend it.
- For this example, find [pr2_2dnav_gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_2dnav_gazebo) in the ROS wiki.
- The containing stack is [wg_robots_gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/wg_robots_gazebo).
- Check whether that stack has a released binary package for your system (if it's a supported Ubuntu distribution).
- If so, `apt-get` the corresponding Debian package name:

  `$ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-wg-robots-gazebo`
- If not, download the stack from its source repository:
- The source URI is listed on [the stack wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/wg_robots_gazebo), for this example `https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/wg_robots_gazebo/trunk`.
- Use rosinstall like [the example here](http://answers.ros.org/question/165/for-new-package-downloading) to add that stack to your ROS tree.
- Compile the new package and its dependencies:

  `$ rosmake pr2_2dnav_gazebo --rosdep-install`

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 35

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-28**:
unstable means you shouldn't expect the code to keep working, nor have a consistent API you can build on.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-28**:
Thank you~And I have a simple question: what's the word 'unstable' means? I have tried the example slam work correctly. It hasn't output any error or crashed.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-28**:
It needs to be fixed; you could potentially install from source, but, in general, the wg_robots_gazebo stack is not a stable set of software that you should depend on.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-27**:
So is there any replacement stacks? Or just losing these kind of useful functions?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-27**:
wg-robots-gazebo is currently not available in Diamondback due to compatibility issues.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-26**:
When I use apt-get dist-upgrade,I found that 'sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-wg-robots-gazebo' says wg-robots-gazebo can't be found. What's the new stack for wg-robots-gazebo?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-25**:
In addition to the wiki page, you can also type "roslocate info stack_name", which will tell you the full version control information for it.